# Location Manager in seperate class in Swift

Tags: swift, class, cllocationmanager, code-separation

so I am currently working on some project and I encountered this issue. If I use CLLocationDelegate in ViewController, it runs normally, however when I try to separate this in its own class, it just doesn't work. When I try to run it just doesn't run the function bellow. Any advice is appreciated :)

View controller:

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON

class TodayViewController: UIViewController {

var locationManager = CLLocationManager()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
 locationRequest.init()
    }    
 }
```

LocationManager class:

```
    import Foundation
    import CoreLocation

 class locationRequest: NSObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
var locationManager = CLLocationManager()

override init() {
    
    print("before super.init()")
    
    super.init()
    
    print("after super.init()")
    
    if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
        print("before setting delegate")
        locationManager.delegate = self
        
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        print("after setting delegate")
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyThreeKilometers
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    print("didUpdate")
    if let location: CLLocationCoordinate2D = manager.location?.coordinate {
        print(location.latitude)
        print(location.longitude)
          }
       }

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
    print("didFail")
    print(error.localizedDescription)
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all please name custom structs and classes with starting uppercase letter.

The error occurs because there is no strong reference to the `locationRequest` class.

Either design the class as singleton

```
class LocationRequest: NSObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    static let shared = LocationRequest()

    ...   

}

...

class TodayViewController: UIViewController {

    var locationRequest = LocationRequest.shared

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
```

or create a lazy instantiated property

```
class LocationRequest: NSObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate { ... }

...

class TodayViewController: UIViewController {

    lazy var locationRequest = LocationRequest()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }    
}
```